# Google Chrome 86.0.4240.75 Anonymize local IPs exposed by WebRTC

Tags: ip, navegador-web

**Google Chrome 85.0.4183.121** a partir de esta versión la opción de **Anonymize local IPs exposed by WebRTC** figura y funciona bien. Después de la actualización la opción ya no figura. Alguna idea de como habilitar esta opción en la versión de **Google Chrome 86.0.4240.75**

[image]

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no corresponde a una pregunta sobre programación o herramientas de programación.